# Stopping students handing in others visual studio 2012 projects (lazy cheating)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, project

I'm an assisting marking student work being handed in (vb.net programming projects, absolute beginners).

With other MS products we filter out most of the lazy cheaters simply by looking at the Authors embedded in the property's of the file.

- Is there a way to uniquely identify the project author or originating computer a project came from?
- Is there a simple way to embed a unique code into each starter project hidden from students?

Comment: hidden might be difficult but if they don't know you could just embed a simple xml-comment into the solution/project file ;)

Comment: on the other hand wouldn't a simple text-compare not be enough to catch the really lazy ones?

Comment: There is actually some very serious academic research in this area with some opensource tools available, including classification or clustering based on the raw text or on the generated binary code. http://www.aicbt.com/authorship-attribution/ and http://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/paradyn/papers/Rosenblum11Authorship.pdf . You may want to reach out to some of these researchers and see if they can point you to any opensource tools to do just this (I've heard of there being such projects before, but I can't recall their names).

Comment: while I find this really fascination isn't it a bit sad to have to use such measures to teach absolute beginners? IMO if they are to lazy to do their homework they will fail soon or later anyway - let them cheat their way through homework and do a final exam on premise (or with different tasks)

Comment: Its part of our program to bring foreign students into the realm of real western education.  To fail is one thing.  To suffer disgrace from cheating and risk being removed from the school is a much faster learning curve and has a wonderful knock on effect in the next few years.  Works well with privileged kids who think they can pay there way through.  Being kicked out of school is shaming and discourages further cheating attempts, including assisting cheating.  Its just one of many  approaches we use. Thanks for the suggestions. :)

Comment: hey no problem and good luck

Comment: Just have students write a short, one-page essay explaining how and why their app works. At lease they'd have to understand the plagiarized code at a minimum, and something good comes out of it. :)